# ClickOnce Upgrade Settings Failing

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, clickonce

I have a .net 5 wpf windows application I'm trying to deploy using click once.  Everything works as far as the install but every time I publish a new version the user settings get wiped out. We have the normal upgrade settings code that runs on startup and works on our .net 4.* apps, but not in this app.

```cs
        /// <summary>
        /// Attempt to copy user settings from previous application version if necessary.
        /// Reset to default on failure.
        /// </summary>
        private static void UpgradeSettings()
        {
            try
            {
                if (!Settings.Default.UpdateSettings)
                {
                    return;
                }

                Settings.Default.Upgrade();
                Settings.Default.UpdateSettings = false;
                Settings.Default.Save();
            }
            catch
            {
                Settings.Default.Reset();
                Settings.Default.Save();
            }
        }
```

The above code is the prescribed method for keeping user settings up to date without overwriting them with default.

The publish profile looks like the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationRevision>0</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>0.9.4.0</ApplicationVersion>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>True</BootstrapperEnabled>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <CreateDesktopShortcut>True</CreateDesktopShortcut>
    <CreateWebPageOnPublish>True</CreateWebPageOnPublish>
    <GenerateManifests>True</GenerateManifests>
    <Install>True</Install>
    <InstallFrom>Web</InstallFrom>
    <InstallUrl>http://softwareurl/Entry/</InstallUrl>
    <IsRevisionIncremented>False</IsRevisionIncremented>
    <IsWebBootstrapper>True</IsWebBootstrapper>
    <MapFileExtensions>True</MapFileExtensions>
    <MinimumRequiredVersion>0.9.4.0</MinimumRequiredVersion>
    <OpenBrowserOnPublish>False</OpenBrowserOnPublish>
    <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
    <ProductName>Entry</ProductName>
    <PublishDir>\\server\Entry\</PublishDir>
    <PublishUrl>\\server\Entry\</PublishUrl>
    <PublisherName>Name</PublisherName>
    <PublishProtocol>ClickOnce</PublishProtocol>
    <PublishReadyToRun>False</PublishReadyToRun>
    <PublishSingleFile>False</PublishSingleFile>
    <SelfContained>False</SelfContained>
    <SignatureAlgorithm>(none)</SignatureAlgorithm>
    <SignManifests>False</SignManifests>
    <SuiteName>SuiteName</SuiteName>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UpdateEnabled>True</UpdateEnabled>
    <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
    <UpdateRequired>True</UpdateRequired>
    <WebPageFileName>install.html</WebPageFileName>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.NetCore.DesktopRuntime.5.0.x64">
      <Install>true</Install>
      <ProductName>.NET Desktop Runtime 5.0.12 (x64)</ProductName>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

What I think is happening is each installation on the client's computer is getting its own hashed project folder name for each version (Not sure where this hash is coming from).  Rather than having a folder structure in %AppData%:

- SuiteName.Entry_Url_0c30snjivs0ryv1opvecv3wuyi2iij41

  - 0.9.7.1

    - user.config
  - 0.9.7.2

    - user.config
  - 0.9.8.3

    - user.config

It is generating something like:

- SuiteName.Entry_Url_0c30snjivs0ryv1opvecv3wuyi2iij41

  - 0.9.7.1

    - user.config
- SuiteName.Entry_Url_cxyuxrqaurh5ey5ua1qyzyf21xe1x0oy

  - 0.9.7.2

    - user.config
- SuiteName.Entry_Url_vaozhrbtrpe1z51r3v4l5jdegucawxsm

  - 0.9.8.3

    - user.config

So the update doesn't go up another directory to look for other versions when calling `System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Upgrade()`.  I've tried changing all of the properties in the clickonce profile, tried adding the app.config files manually to the project and everything in between.

Comment: I thought so too, and the same setup works on .net 4.8, but in this case it is not.  I would like to know where the hash is coming from.  I really think that may be the hangup.

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66477181/clickonce-and-net-5-user-settings-not-updated)?

Comment: No I hadn't, signing the assembly fixed it!  The folder name was changed on the client computer `SuiteName.Entry_StrongName_3cssvt4xbczj0ocjlkevedir3hpondkv`